# Is there a way to rebuild only part of a disk in an mdraid5 setup?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, software-raid

Last night I accidentally used `dd` to overwrite the first ~20GB of a drive in a RAID5 array.  When I noticed, I repaired the array with

```
$ mdadm --fail /dev/md127 /dev/sdb
$ mdadm --remove /dev/md127 /dev/sdb
$ mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb
$ mdadm --add /dev/md127 /dev/sdb
```

but it took a while because it's a 3TB disk.  Since `dd` printed out the number of bytes copied, I knew exactly how much of the drive needed to be rebuilt.  Was there a way I could have repaired only those bytes?

Comment: It's possible that `dd`ing back from the remaining disk would have worked, depending on how RAID organizes its metadata.

Comment: @TomHunt I would believe that for RAID 1, but for RAID 5 no disks have identical contents so I'd be surprised if that worked (even if I fixed the metadata manually)

Comment: Ah, I missed the raid5 bit somehow. It's true, that wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm inclined to think there's no way to do it. Rebuild time isn't necessarily something they're optimizing for, since you can use the array normally during rebuild. (Unless that's different for raid5 as well? I've only ever used raid1.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes: you can create a custom write-intent bitmap, or tell `mdadm` to assemble an array from only the beginnings of the disks, or probably some tricks I haven't thought of.

In practice, trying to do so carries a high risk of data loss: you're bypassing the system's safeguards, so it can't protect you from getting your disks mixed up, or incorrectly specifying where the array begins, or other user errors.  It's safer just to let the normal rebuild process run.